# MS SQL Update Date Only

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

All,

Is there a way in SQL to update a datetime field and only change the date? I have a year's worth of data in datetime format (YYYY-MM-DD XX:XX:XX.XXX) and would like the set date for every value to be 12/30. I do not want to change the time or the year.

I tried the following but with no luck:

```
UPDATE table
SET DATEPART(MONTH,[date]) = 12 WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,[date]) = 2016
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Have you tried with the DATEADD function instead? You will probably need to compare the date to 12/30, get the date diff THEN use DATEADD to add days to the original date.

Comment: The issue is that I have a whole year's worth of dates, so I can't just add one value and fix them all.

Comment: Please tag with the version of SQL Server for which your question applies.  Also, is your source field a `datetime` or `datetime2`?

Comment: It's SQL Server 2008 and it is a datetime field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in SQL 2008:

```
Update table
    set [date] = '12/30/' + cast(datepart(year,[date]) as char(4)) + ' ' + convert(varchar(20),[date],114)
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,[date]) = 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

> **EDIT - UPDATE for 2008 - Convert() and Stuff()**

```
Declare @YourTable table (date datetime)
Insert Into @YourTable values
 ('2017-05-11 13:17:26.350')
,('2016-07-29 09:22:56.350')

Select Date
      ,stuff(convert(varchar(25),[date],25),6,5,'12-30')
 From @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Date                      (No column name)
2017-05-11 13:17:26.350   2017-12-30 13:17:26.350
2016-07-29 09:22:56.350   2016-12-30 09:22:56.350
```

**So to apply an update**

```
Update YourTable 
   set [date] = stuff(convert(varchar(25),[date],25),6,5,'12-30')
 Where DatePart(YEAR,[date]) = 2016
```